# How add an image to a nested object in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-9

I am trying to add a file type image to my nested object, below i have added my handle change where i am trying to get the image into the nested object.

```
const handleImage = (e, docketIndex, i) => {
const list = { ...inputList }
list.product_information[i].docket_numbers[docketIndex]['imageURL'] = e.target.files[0]
console.log(list)
setInputList(list)
```

}

Below is the result of the above code which shows an empty object in JSON stringify

```
product_information": [
{
  "docket_numbers": [
    {
      "imageURL": {}
    }
  ],
```

But when i console log the handle change results is below which is a working as expected

[image]

But when i try to send the image to the backend its shows and empty object. i have tried adding an image using Formdata before but i am trying achieve this without using Formdata.